# Why can't I dereference this iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

```
template <class In, class V>
In my_find(In begin, In end, V val)
{
    /*
    while (begin != end)
    {
        if ((*begin) == val)
            return begin;
        ++begin;
    }
    */
    while (begin != end || *begin != val)
        ++begin;
    return begin;
}
```

I've been trying to implement find but without much success. I can't figure out why the code commented out works while the other one keeps getting a message saying "cannot dereference out of range vector iterator".

Comment: This should be `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: If `begin == end` then `*begin != val` will be evaluated which - when `end` is truly a "past the end" iterator - gives undefined behaviour.    To only evaluate `*begin != val` if `begin != end`, change the `while` condition to `begin != end && *begin != val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd while loop is a logic error. It basically means if either condition satisfies, the loop should be executed. Therefore it keeps incrementing *begin until it reaches a point where it goes out of range.
Try changing the | | with &&. This would mean that both conditions need to be satisfied for the loop to execute which is exactly what your commented code does.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `||` operation which means for the condition in `while()` to be evaluated both of the expressions should be evaluated.

Therefore even when `begin != end` is `false` it will still evaluate the next expression which is `*begin != val`. When begin equals off-the-end iterator this means you're trying to dereference the off-the-end iterator which is not safe and potentially causes undefined behavior.